# How to combine dql queries

Tags: dql

I have two DQL queries

`$dql = "SELECT i FROM Edufaction\Bundle\EdufactionBundle\Entity\Institute i JOIN i.instsummary s where s.instaffiliation IN ($affiliation1)";`

`$dql = "SELECT i FROM Edufaction\Bundle\EdufactionBundle\Entity\Institute i where i.institutefeerange IN ($feerange)";`

how do I combine these two queries into single query?

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this using the AND operator

```
$dql = "SELECT i FROM Edufaction\Bundle\EdufactionBundle\Entity\Institute i JOIN i.instsummary s where s.instaffiliation IN ($affiliation1) AND  i.institutefeerange IN ($feerange)";
```